# How to extend multiple templates in Blade (Laravel 5)?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-blade

I have the following files:

**foo.blade.php**

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Foo Template</h1>
      @yield('content')
   </body>
</html>
```

**bar.blade.php**

```
<h2>Bar Template</h2>
<div class="bar-content">
@yield('bar-content')
</div>
```

I want to create another file that is able to extend both the above templates. e.g something like this:

```
@extends('foo')
@section('content')
     <p>Hello World</p>
     @extends('bar')
     @section('bar-content')
          <p>This is in div.bar-content</p>
     @endsection
@endsection
```

To give:

```
<html>
   <head>
   </head>
   <body>
      <h1>Foo Template</h1>
      <p>Hello World</p>
      <h2>Bar Template</h2>
      <div class="bar-content">
          <p>This is in div.bar-content</p>
      </div>
   </body>
</html>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 16):

Use multiple files.
for eg;

layout.blade.php:

```
@include('header')

@yield('layout_content')

@include('footer')
```

second.blade.php

```
@extends('layout')

@section('layout_content')

<div>
@yield('second_content')
</div>

@stop
```

third.blade.php

```
@extends('second.blade.php')

@section('second_content')

<h1>Hello World!</h1>

@stop
```

You can include @yield in any of the parent files and can be used in the child

Answer (score 5):

I would recommend using [components](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/blade#components-and-slots). Here is [an example](https://gist.github.com/jacurtis/09354df671e2c48eafe7a5cb91bb0f41).

It seems to me `layout/include` has a weird logic when there are many of them and you start nesting them. Components are pretty straight forward. For these nested structures you are building there, components also have slots.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know if this will work, but try `@include` instead of `@extends` for your `bar` template. The put your section for `bar` below the other section (not nested). I did not tested this, so I hope it works ;)

// EDIT:

Try it with an if-statement in your `foo` file:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <h1>Foo Template</h1>
    @yield('content')

    @if(isset($displayBar) && $displayBar == true)
        @include('dashboard.test.bar')
    @endif
    </body>
</html>
```

And now the child view:

```
@extends('dashboard.test.foo')
@section('content')
    <p>Hello World</p>
@endsection

<?php $displayBar = true ?>

@section('bar-content')
    <p>This is in div.bar-content</p>
@endsection
```

Comment: What does it give you as output? Is there any error?

Comment: No error. Everything appears except the: `<p>This is in div.bar-content</p>` portion of the code

Comment: Ok, I believe it is not as easy as I wish it was, but you could put the `@include` into your `foo` file below `@yield` and then it would work.

If you dont want to display the `bar` template in every child view, put an if statement with a flag onto it...

Answer (score 1):

I think it's not possible to do what you want here, at least without extending Blade:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/blade#extending-blade

If I were you, I'd rearchitectured my views hierarchy to keep things simple.

Answer (score -4):

```
@php
$ext = '';
@endphp
@if (Request::segment(1)=='explications')
@php
$ext = '_explications'
@endphp
@endif
@extends('pages_templates/template_page_fluid'.$ext)
```

Comment: While what you have written may answer the question, however it does seem a little lacking in [explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) and may illicit confusion to other users. Can you please expand upon your answer so that it is clearer and more accessible? This will make for better answers and help future users understand how the problem was solved.